# Reference to captured group value with \g<...>

Tags: regex, search, intellij-idea, ide, phpstorm

I have a pattern like this

```
absint\(\s?(\$[A-Za-z0-9_]+)\s?\)\s?={2,3}\s?\g<1>|(\$[A-Za-z0-9_]+)\s?==\s?absint\(\s?\g<2>\s?\)
```

which findes code like `$id == absint($id)` or `$id == absint($id)`. It works fine with preg_match function, in https://regex101.com but PHPStorm doesn't support this syntax. How can I do exactly the same thing in PHPStorm search ?

Comment: If replacing `\g<1>` with `(?1)` does not work. BTW, didn't you want to actually use `\1` instead of `\g<1>`? Also, *which findes code like `$id == absint($id)` or `$id == absint($id)`* - what is the difference between the two?

Comment: Wiktor thanks for reply. Hope someone will offer solution

Comment: There is no difference. I want to find both and refactor it which I have done.I just wonder.

About \1 i didn't know. Thanks for advise

Comment: Ok, I see you want to match either `$id == absint($id)` or `absint($id2) === $id2`.

Comment: @WiktorStribizew exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you cannot use recursion in PHP Storm. You may repeat the pattern though:

```
absint\(\s?\$\w+\s?\)\s?={2,3}\s?\$\w+|\$\w+\s?={2,3}\s?absint\(\s?\$\w+\s?\)
           ^^^^^                 ^^^^^ ^^^^^                       ^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/P0jgtz/1) (JS flavor chosen that does not support pattern recursion).

The `\w` matches letters, digits or underscores, and in case of a non-Unicode-aware regex, is equal to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

Now, if you mean to only match the *same variables on both ends*, you may use *backreferences* (instead of the recursion constructs):

```
absint\(\s?(\$\w+)\s?\)\s?={2,3}\s?\1|(\$\w+)\s?={2,3}\s?abs‌​int\(\s?\2\s?\)
           xxxxxxx                 xx yyyyyyy                       yy
```

Backreferences do not repeat (reuse) the group patterns (as is the case with `\g<1>` or `(?1)`), but they are placeholders for the *text* captured with the corresponding groups.

See [**Using Backreferences To Match The Same Text Again**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) vs. [**Regular Expression Subroutines**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html).

Comment: I have already done this task by the way above. I am just wondering is it possible with recursion. Seems it isn't. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: If you mean to only match the same variables on both ends, you may use [`absint\(\s?(\$\w+)\s?\)\s?={2,3}\s?\1|(\$\w+)\s?={2,3}\s?absint\(\s?\2\s?\)`](https://regex101.com/r/P0jgtz/2).

Comment: It works !!! but I can't understand the difference between this one and my version. Please explane me

Comment: I updated the answer to explain the difference between the subroutine calls and backreferences, if you need a deeper explanation please let me know what is still unclear.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I understand it.